# Can I use Imagemagick to unrotate Canon RAW pictures in batch?

Tags: raw, imagemagick

I’d like to use Freds unroate script to unrotate a bunch of Canon *.cr2 RAW files and keep them in the RAW Format. I’m able to use the script as a batch file for a folder of jpgs:

```
for pic in *.jpg; do echo "... bearbeite "$pic; unrotate -f 10 $pic ${pic%.*}"_cuted".jpg; done
```

The simple command would be

```
unrotate image.jpg unroteted_image.jpg
```

If I try to unrotate only one cr2 image, I get the following error Message:

```
convert: no encode delegate for this image format `CR2' @ warning/constitute.c/WriteImage/1175.
```

---

```
identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-12-18
http://www.imagemagick.org
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

---

```
identify -list format

CR2  DNG       r--   Canon Digital Camera Raw Image Format
```

---

Am I missing something? A delegate to write CR2 files?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you install ImageMagick? What OS are you using?

Comment: Seems like an installation problem

Comment: I’m using macOS 10.11 and installed via homebrew (`brew install imagemagick`)

Comment: Canon raw files aren't rotated. Only the instruction regarding which way to display the file in the metadata attached to the file is different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about photography. It is about getting an application to work within a specific operating system.

Comment: I want to use the [unroate script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/unrotate/index.php) to automatically crop and unroate photograped pieces of paper, didn’t specify this, sorry.

Comment: @MichaelClark where could I ask this question then? Sorry to ask something off-topic…

Comment: You can't really crop or rotate a raw file. You can only crop or rotate a conversion of a raw file.

Comment: Hint: what you see on your screen when you "open" a raw image file is NOT the raw image file, it is a conversion of that data into an image that can be displayed by your monitor.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do what you want in imagemagick, but it is relatively easy to use Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* to batch change the instructions appended to raw files to do what you want. The raw data itself is not changed, only the instructions on how each file should be displayed.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What is the problem you actually want to solve, because i'm relatively sure that rotated raw files aren't it. Also, unrotate is for straightening images which were rotated by an arbitrary angle, within a unicoloured box.

Comment: Or try Exiftool. You can use it to reset the orientation tags in the images. You could run it as a batch script.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the output of `identify -list format` that you posted:

```
   Format  Module    Mode  Description
----------------------------------------------------------------
      CR2  DNG       r--   Canon Digital Camera Raw Image Format
```

ImageMagick can only read CR2 format (the "Mode" is `r--`, meaning it can only read).

The error output also indicates the issue: "no **encoder** delegate" for the CR2 image format. It cannot *encode*, or write new information to, CR2 files.

Comment: That’s what I figured, I thought maybe I’m missing a delegate 